# How to import a function from a view.py file and launch a server with a basic view in django?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

The server works fine when I run python3 manage.py runserver on the VSC terminal
But as soon as I try to import a function from a view.py file

```
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django - Coder")
```

to the urls.py file the server doesn't work

I do the from django.view import hello

and I also modify the url by adding the path "hello" of the function

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/' hello)
```

]

But it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/
It will help you better understand the logic of the "path".

In your case it should be something like:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello, name="hello"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do the `from django.view import hello`

```
from django.views import hello
```

You lost a "s" after "view",